# First class example and i have no clue what to do

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

So my first university class in my first year is a linear algebra course for second year and the teacher was explaining fields to us then at the end of the class he asked us this:

$$\begin{align*}F &= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5) \subset \mathbb{R}\\
  &= \{a+b\sqrt5 : a,b \in \Bbb Q\}\end{align*}$$

Show that the inverse exists...

I'm like 100% sure this is a really easy question although i haven't done math in months and haven't done much proofs either so cut me some slack please.

Comment: yea i dont have those buttons on my keyboard sorry

Comment: Are you talking about the equations? If you are, it's done in (La)Tex. It's formed of commands. Example: $\alpha$ is `$\alpha$`.

Comment: See the help -page :How do I format math here?

Comment: This is standard high-school stuff in the United States, and I have difficulty believing that you haven’t seen it there in your country. It’s called “rationalizing the denominator” here.

Comment: well i know about that its just i'm confused about how we are supposed to determine such things for the proof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show that (presumably multiplicative) inverses exist for general members $a+b\sqrt5\in F$. Consider: $$(a+b\sqrt5)(a-b\sqrt5)=a^2-5b^2$$

Do you see now?

Comment: im a little slow at the moment but how does that prove it, i have no clue unfortunately

Comment: What happens if you multiply both sides by the rational number $\dfrac{1}{a^2 - 5b^2}$?

Comment: Oh lol... how are we supposed to know that? just from seeing previous questions? cause i have never seen this before

Comment: If a and b are rational and not both 0, then $a^2-5b^2 \ne 0$ because $\sqrt 5$ is not rational.